# What was the first acting job of Joey Tribbiani seen in Friends?

Tags: friends

[Joey Tribbiani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_Tribbiani) is shown as struggling actor from first season of [Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends). He was shown acting in the fictional soap opera Days of Our Lives (DOOL). He also performs as a body double for the butt for some famous actor in a movie in another episode. He is shown performing many acting roles.

Anyone remember which was the official first cast of Joey Tribbiani in Friends? Was it for a movie or TV show? Which episode was that?

Comment: I think he was Al Pacino's butt........

Comment: He did get the role but they didn't use it because he kept tensing when they filmed. There is a line later on when someone says that no one will even notice it's not him and he responds "My mom will".

Comment: FYI, Days of Our Lives isn't a fictional soap opera. [It's real.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Days_of_Our_Lives)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the pilot episode, it is revealed that Joey was in a play (*Pinocchio*). This would be the first role he has within the show's time frame. Later episodes also talk about work he did before the starting point of the show, including a porn film (which the friends all watch in "The One with Phoebe's Husband").

Comment: " Once I was a wooden boy, a little wooden boy! "  -Chandler

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @jlmmcdonald does answer this, but Joey's first performance in the Friends current timeline (where we join them) is missing.

In Season 1, Episode 6 - "The One with the Butt", Joey performs in a musical titled "Freud!".